# How to connect to cosmos db in ruby file

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-cosmosdb, jruby

I want to connect to Azure cosmos DB in ruby file, Please can anyone suggest how can I connect with the DB , is there any gem available, to which I can pass connection string of that DB .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following info worked for me, I found it here [Connect to CosmosDB using RUBY](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cosmosdb-odbc-ruby.rst)

If you have not already, first specify connection properties in an ODBC DSN (data source name). This is the last step of the driver installation. You can use the Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator to create and configure ODBC DSNs.

You need the following info from CosmosDB

AccountEndpoint: The Cosmos DB account URL from the Keys blade of the Cosmos DB account
AccountKey: In the Azure portal, navigate to the Cosmos DB service and select your Azure Cosmos DB account. From the resource menu, go to the Keys page. Find the PRIMARY KEY value and set AccountKey to this value.

you will need to install the following gems

```
gem install dbi
gem install dbd-odbc
gem install ruby-odbc
```

The write something like this

```
#connect to the DSN
require 'DBI'
cnxn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:CData CosmosDB Source','','')

#execute a SELECT query and store the result set
resultSet = cnxn.execute("SELECT City, CompanyName FROM Customers")

#display the names of the columns
resultSet.column_names.each do |name|
  print name, "\t"
end
puts

#display the results
while row = resultSet.fetch do
  (0..resultSet.column_names.size - 1).each do |n|
    print row[n], "\t"
  end
  puts
end
resultSet.finish

#close the connection
cnxn.disconnect if cnxn
```

Comment: But where are we setting this Account key and AccountEndpoint in the given file.

Comment: If you have not already, first specify connection properties in an ODBC DSN (data source name). This is the last step of the driver installation. You can use the Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator to create and configure ODBC DSNs.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no prerequisite from your side in the question, I'm assuming you want to know the complete procedure to work on Azure CosmosDB using Ruby.

You need to create an Azure storage account and Azure CosmosDB account.
The easiest way to create an Azure storage account is by using the Azure portal. To learn more, see [Create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal).

To create an Azure Cosmos DB Table API account, see [Create a database account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet#create-a-database-account).

To use Azure Storage or Azure Cosmos DB, you must download and use the Ruby Azure package that includes a set of convenience libraries that communicate with the Table REST services.

Use RubyGems to obtain the package

1. Use a command-line interface such as PowerShell (Windows), Terminal (Mac), or Bash (Unix).
2. Type gem install azure-storage-table in the command window to install the gem and dependencies.

Import the package
Use your favorite text editor, add the following to the top of the Ruby file where you intend to use Storage: require "azure/storage/table"

Add your connection string
You can either connect to the Azure storage account or the Azure Cosmos DB Table API account. Get the connection string based on the type of account you are using.

Add an Azure Storage connection
The Azure Storage module reads the environment variables AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT and AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY for information required to connect to your Azure Storage account. If these environment variables are not set, you must specify the account information before using Azure::Storage::Table::TableService with the following code:

Azure.config.storage_account_name = "your Azure Storage account"
Azure.config.storage_access_key = "your Azure Storage access key"

Add an Azure Cosmos DB connection
To connect to Azure Cosmos DB, copy your primary connection string from the Azure portal, and create a Client object using your copied connection string. You can pass the Client object when you create a TableService object:

common_client = Azure::Storage::Common::Client.create(storage_account_name:'myaccount', storage_access_key:'mykey', storage_table_host:'mycosmosdb_endpoint')

table_client = Azure::Storage::Table::TableService.new(client: common_client)

Please refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-ruby) if required.